# Break h2 title instead of moving image

Tags: html, css

So I have a box on my website, which has a title and an image to the right. The issue is that when the width of the screen is too small the image gets pushed down. Instead what I want is that the title breaks to a new line.

I've tried using maxwidth on the h2, and various other options with display, width and position but I can't get it to work. I feel like there should be a trivial solution, but I haven't been able to find it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="projects-container">
     <h2>Title that gets too long</h2><img src="img/ddicon.jpg" width="30px">
     <div id="website">
       <p>I like to build websites, I would like to be better at it. So then this happened.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.projects-container {
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.projects-container > h2 {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  display: inline;
}

.projects-container > img {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make 2 simple changes.

**1-** Place `<img>` first in HTML.

```
<div class="projects-container">
  <img src="img/ddicon.jpg" width="30px">
  <h2>Title that gets too long</h2>
</div>
```

**2-** Remove `display: inline` and add `overflow: hidden`:

```
.projects-container > h2 {
  margin: 5px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

As you are using `float` on child elements, so don't forget to set layout of parent element. There are many ways of setting layout. For example:

```
.projects-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or

```
.projects-container:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: '';
}
```

```css
.projects-container {
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.projects-container > h2 {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.projects-container > img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="projects-container">
    <img src="img/ddicon.jpg" width="30px">
     <h2>Title that gets too long</h2>
     <div id="website">
       <p>I like to build websites, I would like to be better at it. So then this happened.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

width add with `calc` `function`

```
.projects-container > h2 {
  margin: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:calc(100% - 35px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjmxd9f4/